# DevOps Preference: Point Solutions or Single Platform?

Tags: github, gitlab, bitbucket, jira, devsecops

In terms of the software development lifecycle, I'm curious how people feel about point solutions (e.g., Jira, BitBucket, etc.) vs platforms (e.g., GitHub and GitLab)?

1. Do people prefer the traditional point-solution method because the tools are better or specialized to individual teams?
2. Or is the consolidation preferred for efficiency and cost?
3. Is consolidation preferred in theory but hard to implement?

Any and all opinions are appreciated.

Thank you

[I am trying to understand how developers and their teams feel about different solutions. Also would like to know which product(s) are used most.]

Comment: I've never heard the term "point solution" - how is it defined? Why did you put BitBucket in the first, but GitLab into the second category?